# Slight indentation of customised BibLaTeX bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, indentation

I've customised the formatting of some bibliography entry types using `biblatex`.  For reasons unknown, the first line of each customised entry type within the bibliography is slightly indented relative to the adjacent un-customised entry types.  An example of this is shown below:

[image]

Here is an MWE which recreates the above output:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
hyperref=true,
firstinits=true, % render first and middle names as initials
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=99,
style=authoryear,
dashed=false, % re-print recurring author names in bibliography
natbib=true,
useprefix=true, % for inclusion of 'de' 'da' in surname
url=false,
urldate=long,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}



% No unit separator after publication year:
\usepackage{xpatch}\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\nopunct}{}{}

% No month for publication year:
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}

% Use single quotes around titles:
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{{\let~\,#1}} % insert thin spaces between author initials
%\renewcommand*{\bibnamedelimd}{\addlpthinspace} % insert thin spaces between author initials
\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{} % no spaces between author initials (requires biber)
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % insert a comma between author and year in-text citations
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace} % comma as separator in bibliography, not full stop
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % remove 'in:' preceding article title

% Place volume number within parentheses:
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
    \printfield{volume}
    \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbthinspace
    \printfield{number}
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}
    \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Spacing in bibliography:
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{12pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{16pt}% the hanging indent

\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{type}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Available at: \url{#1}}

% Customised `image' entry:
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{image}{
    \printnames{author}
    \newblock
    \printfield{year}
    \newblock
    \printfield{title}
    \newblock
    \printfield{type}
    \addperiod\newunit\newblock
    \printlist{publisher}
    \newblock
    \printfield{url}
    \newblock
    \printfield{addendum}
\finentry}



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Article{Example_Article_1,
  Title                    = {Title 1},
  Author                   = {Smith, A. B. and Jones, D. C.},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {42},
  Volume                   = {10},
  Journal                  = {Example Journal},
}

@Article{Example_Article_2,
  Title                    = {Title 2},
  Author                   = {Smith, A. B. and Jones, D. C.},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {42},
  Volume                   = {10},
  Journal                  = {Example Journal},
}

@Image{Example_Image_1,
  Title                    = {Title 1},
  Url                      = {example.com},
  Addendum                 = {(Accessed: 1 January 2013)},
  Type                     = {Photograph},
  Author                   = {Doe, J. D.},
  Year                     = {2009},
}

@Image{Example_Image_2,
  Title                    = {Title 2},
  Url                      = {example.com},
  Addendum                 = {(Accessed: 2 January 2013)},
  Type                     = {Photograph},
  Author                   = {Doe, J. D.},
  Year                     = {2009},
}

\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\printbibliography[title=References]

\end{document}
```

Do I need to explicitly define a biliography environment using `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` and then adjust `\setlength`, `\itemindent`, and `\leftmargin` to rectify these indentations?

Thanking you in advance,

Baldwin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some `%` in your redefinitions.

It should be

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbthinspace
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}
```

and

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{image}{%
    \printnames{author}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{year}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{title}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{type}%
    \addperiod\newunit\newblock
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{url}%
    \newblock
    \printfield{addendum}%
\finentry}
```

Otherwise LaTeX inserts these unwanted spaces at the beginning of an `@image` entry (which is what you noticed) even though `biblatex` goes to great lengths to avoid superfluous whitespaces.

See also [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864).

Note that it should not be necessary to set `\bibitemsep` and `\bibhang` manually, `biblatex` does a good job finding the right values itself.