# Allignment of footcites with bibliography category

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

If I delete the code between the two command tags, I got the normal footcite result. But with that code, which I use to print a bibliography for each form of publication, I got allignment differences. How could I change this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,dutch]{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=numeric,sorting=nty,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

%Begin
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{websites}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{spoken}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{books}

\AtEveryCitekey{
  \ifentrytype{misc}{
    \iffieldundef{howpublished}{
      \addtocategory{websites}{\thefield{entrykey}}
    }{
      \addtocategory{spoken}{\thefield{entrykey}}
    }
  }{
  }
}

\AtEveryCitekey{
  \ifentrytype{book}{
      \addtocategory{books}{\thefield{entrykey}}
  }{}
}
%End 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{3,
  author = {Menger, Carl},
  title = {Grunds{\"a}tze der Volkswirtschaftslehre},
  publisher = {Braum{\"u}ller},
  year = {1982} 
}
@misc{blockchain1,
  author = {Blockchain},
  title = {{Transactie}},
  url = "https://blockchain.info/tx/1c12443203a48f42cdf7b1acee5b4b1c1fedc144cb909a3bf5edbffafb0cd204",
  urldate = "2014-11-16"
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
Some text\footcite{3} another one\footcite{blockchain1}

and a footnote\footnote{I would like to add a footnote with some information too.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing the `%` signs at the end of lines, see [here why](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864) and  [this for a slightly longer discussion about when a `%` is necessary to avoid space spilling over](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922/35864), a [similar `biblatex` problem can be found here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134522/35864). So instead of `\AtEveryCitekey{` you should have `\AtEveryCitekey{%`, etc. pp.

Comment: Thanks! Please post this comment as answer too so I could mark it as answer.

Comment: I think this had better be closed as a duplicate of the question I linked to above.